# Complex number - arctan

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z=-2+2\sqrt{3}i\implies x=-2, y=2\sqrt3$$
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{4+12}=4$$
$$\text{Angle}=\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt3}{-2}\right)+\pi=\frac{2\pi}{3}=120^\circ$$

1)  May I know how $\arctan\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt3}{-2}\right)+\pi$ turns into $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$?

2) Can I use calculator to do the calculation and how?

Thanks for the kindness!

[image]

Comment: This will help you better format questions/answers in the future. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Since $\arctan\left(-\sqrt3\right)=-\frac\pi3$, $\arctan\left(-\sqrt3\right)+\pi=\frac{2\pi}3$.

Comment: i didn't know  arctan(-{\sqrt 3})= \frac{−π}{3}, may i know what keywords should i google to learn? Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: WHat I wrote was that $\arctan\left(-\sqrt3\right)=-\frac\pi3$. It follows from the fact that $\arctan$ is an odd function and that $\tan\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\sqrt3$. You can learn much more at the [Wikipedia article on inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $\tan(-\theta)=-\tan\theta$ 
$$\therefore \arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt3}{-2}\right)+\pi=\arctan\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)+\pi=-\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi=\frac{2\pi}{3}=120^\circ$$
You can use calculator to find amplitude & argument. Do remember $\tan^{-1}\sqrt3=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know that arctan is the inverse function of tangent.

So, if $\tan(x)=y$, it follows that $\arctan(y):=\tan^{-1}(y)=\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))=x$

In this case, we have $\arctan(-\sqrt3)=\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt3)=-\pi/3$